# Javascript what is difference between `map.set('key',value)` and `map['key']=value`?

Tags: javascript

How does a javascript `Map` work?

```js
function howMapWorks() {
    var map = new Map();
    map['someKey'] = ['a', 'b'];
    map.set('someKey', ['c', 'd']);
    map.forEach((v, k) => {
        console.log(v);
    });
    console.log(map);
}
```

output:

```
[ 'c', 'd' ]
Map(1) { 'someKey' => [ 'c', 'd' ], someKey: [ 'a', 'b' ] }
```

Comment: first is not recommended. use set https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#setting_object_properties

Comment: A `Map`, like practically everything in JavaScript is an object and therefore, you can generally assign any property you want to it